# How to include a section name in the page title?

Tags: set

I can get Craft to generate page titles for entries and individual pages using:

```
{% set title = entry.title %}
```

and

```
{% set title = "News and Insights" %}
```

But I need to be able to generate a full page title for an entry, that includes the section name, for example:

News Item | News and Insights | Company Name

Can anyone please explain how...?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{{ entry.section }} - {{ entry.title }}
```

Here are a list of properties you can get from the Entry model:

https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel

So you could do

```
{% set title = "#{entry.section} | #{entry.title}" %}
```